# ReadFromUDP does not block

Tags: sockets, go

I tried to build a udp server with go and find that method ReadFromUDP of UDPConn does not block the thread. I google that there are some people facing this problem and no solution found.

my system is osx 10.8.2, go version is 1.1.1

code list bellow

```
addr, _ := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "localhost:10234")
conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", addr)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return
}
defer conn.Close()

var buf []byte
for {
    n, remote_addr, _ := conn.ReadFromUDP(buf)
    fmt.Println("from", remote_addr,"got message:", string(buf[:n]))
}
```

I got a list of: `from <nil> got message:`

Answer (score 2):

I believe there's something broken in OSX. Your code, [modified only slightly to not ignore errors etc.](http://play.golang.org/p/lU0ubopXm8), runs just fine on Linux.

Comment: i figure it out, [golang issue](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4796) note that there is problem in osx 10.8.2, but there also is problem in my code

Comment: @enzoyang according to the bug report this is fixed in 10.8.3 . If there isn't anything else preventing you from doing so, it's probably worth the upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I updated my system to osx 10.8.4 codes above does not work right.

i compare [udp server code](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/attachmentText?id=4796&aid=47960000000&name=test.go&token=O8Z6jXncwAEY8mDNesvjRlLVQOk%3A1375086228927) with mine.

and change `var buf []byte` with `buf := make([]byte, 1024)`

it works well now.